# Overwriting error messages from other packages in R

Tags: r, error-handling, package, try-catch, grepl

I want to create my own error message in R to overwrite an error message from another package.  Here is a simple reprex below:

```
myfunc <- function(x,y,string=TRUE){
  
  if(string){
    x+y
  }else{
    print("not numeric")
  }
}

myfunc(2,"yes")
```

This returns:

```
Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I want to overwrite `Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator` with my own error message specific to my package, e.g., `Did you forget to use string=TRUE?`. I have implemented `tryCatch` and `grepl` within the function, and it works, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach:

```
myfunc <- function(x,y,string=TRUE){
  
  tryCatch(myfunc(x,y),
           error=function(err){
             if (grepl("non-numeric", err$message)) {
               stop("Did you forget to use string=TRUE?")
             }
           })
  
  if(string){
    x+y
  }else{
    print("not numeric")
  }
}

myfunc(2,"yes")
```

This returns:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Did you forget to use string=TRUE?
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Called from: value[[3L]](cond)
```

Which is what I want, although I'd prefer that it didn't say `Error in value[[3L]](cond)`. Is there a way to get rid of that? Also, is this the best way to overwrite error messages, or is there another approach that is better?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `stop` maybe use `message` ?

```
myfunc <- function(x,y,string=FALSE){
  
  if(!string){
    tryCatch(x+y, error = function(err) {
      if (grepl("non-numeric", err$message)) {
        message("Error : Did you forget to use string=TRUE?")
      }
    })
  }else{
    print("not numeric")
  }
}

myfunc(2,"yes")
#Error : Did you forget to use string=TRUE?

myfunc(2,4)
#[1] 6

myfunc(2,"yes", string = TRUE)
#[1] "not numeric"
```

Comment: This works -- but now it also prints the default error message: `Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  Any ideas as to how to hide that?

Comment: It does not print the default message for me. It only prints `Error : Did you forget to use string=TRUE?`. Did you run my function in the console?

Comment: Ohh, I see you changed more than one thing.  I'm following now, and it did work.  However, when I run `myfunc(2,"yes",string=TRUE)`, I'm still getting `Error : Did you forget to use string=TRUE?`

Comment: Yes, that is because `string` is still `TRUE`. I think you need a different logic than what you had in your post. See my updated answer if that is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks.  This works well for this example, but not for my function, unfortunately (I think I simplified it too much).  This gives me a lot to work off of, though, so, thank you!!